# Global redirect based on logic in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an ASP.NET MVC3 computer support ticketing portal.

There is a maintenance state, where it is best to forbid the users from interacting with EF/Database, to avoid "collisions" I am currently getting.

I have an `IMaintenanceDispatcher` that has a boolean property `IsOnMaintenance` set to true by the business logic, whenever a background logic puts the portal in that state.

I need to redirect client requests to a parking page for the time of maintenance.

Where do I place the logic that will check if the `IsOnMaintenance` is true, and if so, do a redirect to a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in an `ActionFilterAttribute` and apply that attribute to any applicable actions/controllers or globally.

```
public class IsOnMaintenanceAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //You'll need to setup your IoC to inject this
    public IMaintenanceDispatcher InjectedMaintenanceDispatcher { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        object ticketIdObj;
        if (!filterContext.ActionParameters.TryGetValue("ticketId", out ticketIdObj))
            return;

        //Make sure it exists
        if (InjectedMaintenanceDispatcher.IsOnMaintenance(int.parse(ticketIdObj)))
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                action = "parkingpage",
                controller = "maintenance",
                area = "ticket" });

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, your action method parameters needs to contain a variable named `ticketId` for the `filterContext.ActionParameters.TryGetValue` to work.

Note: I had assumed that an individual ticket is put into maintenance mode and you were wanting to check for that... but re-reading the question it seems like you want to put the whole area/site on hold. Even with that case, the `ActionFilterAttribute` example still holds... just not as different.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but is there perhaps a way that would not require me to decorate every single controller with redirect functionality like this?

Comment: Will it be a global thing? If so, you can call something like `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new IsOnMaintenanceAttribute())` inside `Application_Start`... that will add it globally. If you don't want it to be global, but still need it on many controllers... I would use a base class/controller.

Comment: It works. Just if I set it globally, I get the redirect loop for the Maintenance action also. So I need a way to conditionally check if the requested action isn't the one I am redirecting a client to. I guess I can check from within the filter code.